# View is not added to super view.?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, constraints

I have added a view from storyboard set all necessary constraint , in iPhone 6s plus view is showing but for other iPhone the view is not showing (its not added to the superview).
I don't know why this happening .?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you used the view hierarchy inspector? Have you printed the view hierarchy?

Comment: Try to NSLog your view frame, give it a color. I think it is added to your super but it is misplaced. It this is the case, make proper constraints relative to sv.

Comment: can you provide more details?

Comment: I have nslog its superview , its nil

Comment: @EmilioPelaez i have not used the view hierarchy but nslog its superview that is nil and also i check the frame which is also not the same that i set from storyboard, its smaller